# Connecting to SSH/RDP/VNC through one machine?

Tags: ssh, vmware, vnc, rdp

I am asked to come up with a solution for connection to ssh, vnc and rdp services in company firewall/proxy via one box on DMZ.

The task is to get users to connect to this one box and then to the service they would like to connect to.

Currently, I have one ubuntu machine on DMZ used for ssh. Users ssh to Ubuntu-DMZ and then to their target machine and the idea is to the same for VNC and RDP.

The solution should be open source/ubuntu where possible?

Comment: What do you intend with "box"? I use SSHPlus to achieve similar issues, but don't know if could help.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a machine used for hopping

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to achive using the localforward of ssh:

Lets say you have a host GATEWAY and a host RDPSERVER which is reachable from GATEWAY. You want to give your user access to RDPSERVER:5900 when logged in on GATEWAY.

Users log in to GATEWAY using

```
ssh -N -L 33642:RDPSERVER:5900 user@GATEWAY
```

This opens a port 33642 on the users machine, which is transparently forwarded to RDPSERVER:5900. So, user can fire up an RDP viewer, point it to localhost:33642 and all data will be encrypted and tunneld to GATEWAY and from there to RDPSERVER.
Once the user is logged in, he can check that the connection is up using

```
telnet localhost 33642
```

If you need several services to possibly different hosts, just add more instances of the -L parameter

On unix hosts, it may be best to distribute a ssh config file with the parameters.

As you can see, ssh has great features (and there is much more than localforward, check out remoteforwards and dynamic port forwards).

Comment: This is usefull to know but users wouldn't know what to do and they will be on Windows machines mostly

Comment: On windows machines, you can do the same thing with putty:

- start an ssh connection to the rdpserver
- run the vnc/rdp viewer to localhost

There are vncviewers that combine both, also iSSH on the ipad has that function.